# A symmetric matrix for a cubic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a monic cubic polynomial $P(x)$ having all its roots real. Is it possible to construct a symmetric nondiagonal matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $P(x)$? If possible, then how to construct it?

Comment: Such a thing would imply the roots of the polynomial were real, assuming you have a real symmetric matrix in mind.  Not all monic cubic real polynomials have real roots.

Comment: The eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are real, and not all polynomials have real roots.

Comment: The polynomial $P(x)$ is assumed to have real roots only.

Comment: Then just take a diagonal matrix with the roots being the entries.

Comment: @Nitin : Sorry! Whether a nondiagonal matrix is possible?

Comment: @G_0_pi_i_e Sure, that is possible. First, take the diagonal one. Name it $D$. Then choose any orthogonal matrix $U$ and put $A = UDU^T$. Then $A$ will have the characteristic polynomial $P$. Note that all your desired matrices can be constructed like this.

Comment: Note that is not possible if $P(x)=(x-1)^3$.